# How to select the second of a nest of divs to set its border

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I am trying to give a border color for second div, but I cannot add id or class names to the second div.

Providing the code below, is there any special selector in CSS to achieve it?

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="d3">
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: define `second div`

Comment: `$('#d3').parent().addClass('some_class')` or `$('#d3').parent().css('border-color' : color)`

Comment: Are you using d3.js???

Comment: @MrKen hey I should use only css not js

Comment: hmm, Remember that yesterday I saw a jquery tag? Sorry.

Comment: I found this link :D [link](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/)

Answer (score 1):

## Depending on other considerations

We can use [the `>` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to specify the immediate child.

```css
div {
    padding: 10px 25px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

body > div > div {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="d3">
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent of the div element with id d3.

```js
document.getElementById('d3').parentElement.style.border = "solid #FF0000";
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="d3">sss
            <div>
                <div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey I should use only css not js

Comment: @texirv if you just want to use css, you can use [Fred Gandt's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44212611/6521116). You also can add `id` for the first `div` , then use `#id > div` to select the second `div`. For not there is now parent selector for css. Refer to [is there a CSS parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/6521116)